# How do I get the angle of my Object and project a 3d Plane on it?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, math, image-processing, 3d

I want to project a plane (for the Base of my Projection). So I think I need the angle of the glove I observe (refer to images below).

Any Ideas how to accomplish that ?

What I do have is the white box and the pinkish Hull around the Glove. Now I need a way to project the Globus onto the glove. And for that I thought I start off with a basic plane (described above).

Any thoughts ?

ExampleOne
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM6Qn.jpg

Example Two
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Ft0.jpg

Comment: I would post an Image but I cant due to repuation issues -...-

Comment: Given the corners of the white box are known, this boils down to basic trigonometry and has absolutely nothing to do with any of your tags. Please consider changing these tags, which is likely to increase the chance of finding somebody explaining it.

Comment: This is way complicated, and much too broad for SO. I suggest you divide the problem into smaller problems, try to solve each of those, and ask here when you get stuck on specific programming-related problems.

Comment: I will thank you :)